# What does “Progress: %” refer to in the loading screen?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In *No Man’s Sky: Beyond*, there was a slight change to the loading screen. Below the star systems with visible names, it now includes “Progress: %”

[image: Progress Percentage]

What does this percentage refer to?

I did not see this mentioned in the patch notes, and in my efforts to figure this out, the only “progress” I am able to find is referring to progress of bug fixes.

Comment: Best guess is that is your percentage complete for that star system for things that you scan like flora and fauna across the planets in the system.

Comment: @TimmyJim That’s a good theory. The next time I’m on, I’ll see if those star systems are in my list of discoveries

Comment: hmm. I wonder if it's a global percentage then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a little while longer, the percentage has nothing to do with the star system itself. It represents how much of the game has loaded prior to loading your character.

I noticed this after the game crashed a couple of times, and forced me go back into the loading screen. The percentage starts off small, and progressively increases until the game loads.